¿Como obtener el total de registros de un SP con C#?
Estoy realizando una consulta con un SP a mi bd la cual si ejecuto el sp desde BD me da un total de registros de 677 pero cuando lo ejecuto desde codigo me da un total de 520.
Este es mi método para obtener los registros:
        public static List<DetalleDepositosEnGarantiaM> QuitarDuplicadosDetalleDepositosEnGarantia()
    {
        var detalleDepoList = new List<DetalleDepositosEnGarantiaM>();

        try
        {
            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Conexion.ObtieneConexionBD()))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string query = "AnticiposQuitarDuplicadosEstadoDeCuenta";

                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    using(var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            detalleDepoList.Add(new DetalleDepositosEnGarantiaM()
                            {
                                IdDeposito = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["IdDeposito"].ToString()) ? dr["IdDeposito"].ToString() : "",
                                StrFolio = dr["strFolio"].ToString()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return detalleDepoList;
    }

Si inspecciono mi variable var dr puedo ver que si obtiene los 677

Pero al momento que regreso la lista solo me trae 520

¿Como puedo hacer para que me traiga todos mis registros? Me ayudarían mucho diciéndome mi error.

Probaste sacar el try catch, a ver si no esta ocurriendo un error?

Lo que estuve viendo es que cuando realizo mi operador ternario en varios datos que llegan como nulos de mi bd, entonces voy a mandar todo mi modelo a los tipos de datos originales en mi BD, que es lo que pasa con el IdDeposito.
